# Manage tableview cell after reloading cell from tableview, Data in textfield is not getting clear

Tags: ios, swift

initial point App start screenshot

[image: initial point App start screenshot]

the second screenshot when I add new cell

[image: the second screenshot when I add new cell]

after adding third and fourth cell

[image: after adding third and fourth cell]

after fifth it reload the cell again

[image: after fifth it reload the cell again]

UITableviewcell containing text field. Each cell text field should contain different data. when user enter.

My issue is when table view load with a first cell(Individual 1). when I add next cell(Individual 2) and continue adding cell(Individual 3, Individual 4) as shown in the screenshot. when I add the cell(Individual 5) the cell(Individual 5) with text field reload the same data of a cell of (Individual 1). The cell of the individual 5 text field should be empty.

But I cannot manage the cell and clear the text field when they reload the cell?

I am new in swift...
Please HELP!!

Thx in advances...

```
class ViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var addmore: UIButton!
var ar = ["Individual 1"]

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ar.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableTVC
    cell.indivuallbl.text! = ar[indexPath.row ]
   return cell
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 240.5
}

@IBAction func deleterow(_ sender: Any) {

    let point = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableview)
    guard let indexPath = tableview.indexPathForRow(at: point) else {
        return
    }
    ar.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    print(ar.count)



}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSLog("a", 1)
    addmore.layer.cornerRadius = 5


}




@IBAction func addmore(_ sender: Any) {


    ar.insert("Individual \(ar.count + 1 )", at: ar.count)
    print(ar.count)
    let myIndexPath = IndexPath(row: ar.count-1 , section: 0)
    tableview.insertRows(at: [myIndexPath], with: .bottom)


}
```

Comment: It would be great if you add code related to Add New cell.

Comment: This is the standard behavior as cells are reused. You – the developer – are responsible to set all UI elements to a defined state. Show the code of `cellForRow`

Comment: I have added the code above @Kuldeep

Comment: Thank you @vadian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TableView Cell reuse itself. Everytime it reused, prepareForReuse method is called. Override this method of your cell. Set values to nil.

Refer this link:- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    // Clean up all values

}
```

Comment: override methods should be written in uitableviewcell?

Comment: Yes. you have to  override it in your custom cell.